# SQL Server Data Import with a "lookup"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, import

I have two databases, on two separate SQL Servers (trying to consolidate both).

This is my setup, and I'm trying to import from Server1:Orders table to Server2:Orders table.

```
Server1
    Database1
        Orders(ID, CustomerName, DateOrdered)

Server2
    Database2
        Customers(ID, Name)
        Orders(ID, CustomerID, DateOrdered)
```

As you can see, Database1 has de-normalized data, and Database2 has the same data, properly normalized.

The issue I'm having is doing the SQL Server import. In Database2, the Customers table is populated, and there WILL be a match between Server1.Database1.Orders.CustomerName and Server2.Database2.Customers.Name.

What I'd LIKE to have happen, is during the import, have the Customer.ID field "looked-up" based on the value of the CustomerName field in the import data, then do the corresponding insert to my new Orders table.

I am able to connect to both servers through SSMS, and I'm trying to do the import via the "SQL Server Native Client 10" as the datasource.

**Update**

It appears I am not going to be able to do an SSIS "package" so what I've done is this:

Moved Database1.Orders to Database2.OrdersOLD.

I'm now looking for a query to create new Order records in Database2.Orders and insert the correctly looked up CustomerID, since now all three tables are within the same database, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SSIS, specifically the [Lookup Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx). See the linked blogs and tutorials from the MSDN article link.

Comment: How and where do I create one of those? Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't figure out how to create one.

Comment: Watch the video on the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc952929.aspx

Comment: You're going to have to create a proper SSIS package, test it and then run it. This is not some magic wizard click in SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be done like this:

```
SELECT O1.ID, C2.ID, O1.DateOrdered
    INTO Server2.Database2.Orders 
    FROM Server1.Database1.Orders O1
    INNER JOIN Server2.Database2.Customers C2 ON C2.Name = O1.CustomerName
```